# Can you draw relative arc segments in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I like the ability of TikZ zo allow absolute and relative positioning and segment definition. However I only ever came across the possiblity to make use of the relative position. Is there also a way to make use of the relative orientation, e.g. of the last segment? A simple example to draw a continous path:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %This produces a continous line of three segments
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2) -- ++(45:2) arc (135:45:2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now Imagine the goal of `++(45:2)` is not to draw a straight segment with 45 degree angle with a length of two, but to draw a segment of length 2 in the same direction as the last segment? And if `arc(135:45:2)` doesn't mean an arc from angle 135 to angle 45 with a radius of 2, but instead means an arc 90 degree to the right starting at the current orientation?

Would it therefore be possible to write something like:

```
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2) -- ++(@:2) -- ++(@:-90:2);
```

meaning

```
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2) -- ++(go 2 units in the same direction as the last segment) -- ++(make a 90 degree turn to the right starting at the direction of the last segment);
```

Looking for any ideas or starting points, e.g. using custom coordinate systems or similar and a way to access the last segment in a path from this coordinate system or any other solution, you could imagine.

Comment: Try the `turtle` TikZ library (cf. section "Turtle Graphics Library", p.847, pgfmanual, v3.1.5b).

Comment: Thanks @PaulGaborit, that seems to be a good starting point, but `turtle` specifically states: However, the direction of the turtle is managed independently of other
path commands.

Comment: Yes. Tikz just remembers the last point on the path. To know the current direction, you need to know the last two points of the path and the shape of the path between these last two points.